# Save image from webservice call in in local PCL folder Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have looked for many examples of this and I believe they are trying to do something different than what want to do.
I have a set of images stored a folder in my pcl. See Image attached.
[PCL Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJxkb.jpg)

Currently I have those images set to embedded resource and they all display in my List View when their name is called. However if an update is made on the server like an image is changed or replaced or added I would like the new image to get saved in the AllImages folder as shown in the image. Is this possible? I've seen a lot of people doing separate dependencies to store the images in the platforms resources/ drawable folder but I don't want I don't want to do that. If i have to change where i am storing my images I can do that as well, but I do need to be able to store the images from the server on my app locally.

I currently have a class dedicated to embedded images, so it would be nice to do it this, but I am not married to the idea.

```
[ContentProperty("ResourceID")] 
    public class EmbeddedImage : IMarkupExtension

    {
        public string ResourceID { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResourceID))
                return null;

            return ImageSource.FromResource(ResourceID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you cannot write to the app bundle at run time - it is cryptographically signed and read-only.  You will have to write any downloaded images to a writable app folder, and your embedded image extension will need to check both locations and return the appropriate one

Comment: Do you recommend writing the path in the database? Also i’m running into an issue accessing the AllImages  folder to see is an image exists. Since it’s readonly could I still access it to check the name?

Comment: Usually we store it in the storage of the devic.

Comment: "running into an issue" - if you want us to help you need to provide a better description of the problem.